# PHP Returning Multiple Rows

Tags: php, html, joomla, html-table, joomla3.0

When I echo my query on screen and run directly in SSMS I get ONE row returned, which is exactly what I am after.  When I run this query in my php I get multiple rows returned (seems to be one for each Dealer).

What should I change in this syntax so that I only have 1 row with totals displayed on screen in php like what happens in my SSMS? --> And if I copy/paste the results of the table into Excel to try and sort, all I have are 0's being displayed in the table, not actual data like what I see returned when I query directly in SSMS

```
    {
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
$Dealer = $_POST['dealer'];

$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql';
$option['host'] = '192.5.100.23';
$option['user'] = 'username';
$option['password'] = 'passs';
$option['database'] = 'test';
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query11 = $db->getquery11(true);
$query11 = "SELECT
MAX(A.Value1) AS Value1,
MAX(A.Value10) AS WorkinIT,
MAX(A.Value11) AS OTG
FROM
(
SELECT
ZT1.Dealer,
SUM(ISNULL(ZT1.[Value1],0)) AS Value1,
0 AS Value10,
0 AS Value11
FROM ROCK AS ZT1
WHERE ZT1.[PUD] >= '$startdate'
AND ZT1.[PUD] <= '$enddate'";
if ($Dealer != 'All') {
$query11 .= " AND ZT1.Dealer = '$Dealer'";
}
$query11 .= " GROUP BY ZT1.Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT
ZT2.Dealer,
0 As Value1,
0 AS Value10,
0 AS Value11
FROM GALL ZT2
WHERE ZT2.[sellD] >= '$startdate'
AND ZT2.[sellD] <= '$enddate'";
if ($Dealer != 'All') {
$query11 .= " AND ZT2.Dealer = '$Dealer'";
}
$query11 .= " GROUP BY ZT2.Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT
Dealer = RTRIM(LTRIM(dealer)),
0 As Value1,
SUM(ISNULL(abc,0)) AS Value10,
0 AS Value11
FROM WorkinIT AS C1
GROUP BY dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT
Dealer = RTRIM(LTRIM(dealer)),
0 As Value1,
0 AS Value10,
SUM(ISNULL(prs,0)) AS Value11
FROM eOTG AS C2";
if ($Dealer != 'All') {
$query11 .= " WHERE C2.Dealer = '$Dealer'";
}

$query11 .= " GROUP BY dealer) AS A";
}

echo $query11;
$db->setquery11($query11);
$query11 = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($query11) 
{
?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Value </th>
<th>OTG </th>
<th>WorkinIT </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ($query11 as $res) 
{
print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->Value1) . "</td>";
print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->WorkinIT) . "</td>";
print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->OTG) . "</td>";
print "</tr>";
}
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the `echo` statement that the above syntax produces that runs fine in SSMS GUI

```
SELECT Max(A.value1)  AS Value1, 
       Max(A.value10) AS WorkinIT, 
       Max(A.value11) AS OTG 
FROM   (SELECT ZT1.dealer, 
               Sum(Isnull(ZT1.[value1], 0)) AS Value1, 
               0                            AS Value10, 
               0                            AS Value11 
        FROM   rock AS ZT1 
        WHERE  ZT1.[pud] >= '2017-06-01' 
               AND ZT1.[pud] <= '2017-06-22' 
        GROUP  BY ZT1.dealer 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ZT2.dealer, 
               0 AS Value1, 
               0 AS Value10, 
               0 AS Value11 
        FROM   gall ZT2 
        WHERE  ZT2.[selld] >= '2017-06-01' 
               AND ZT2.[selld] <= '2017-06-22' 
        GROUP  BY ZT2.dealer 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT dealer = Rtrim(Ltrim(dealer)), 
               0                   AS Value1, 
               Sum(Isnull(abc, 0)) AS Value10, 
               0                   AS Value11 
        FROM   workinit AS C1 
        GROUP  BY dealer 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT dealer = Rtrim(Ltrim(dealer)), 
               0                   AS Value1, 
               0                   AS Value10, 
               Sum(Isnull(prs, 0)) AS Value11 
        FROM   eotg AS C2 
        GROUP  BY dealer) AS A
```

**EDIT 2**
The below image shows what SSMS outputs on the top, and the bottom image is what my php outputs
[image]

Comment: Add some error reporting to your script and you would probably have been told about the MISSING `"` in your code. Or use a decent code editor and code coloring would also have given you a hint

Comment: string concatenation of query variables like this will leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. It would be much more sensible to use prepared statements and parameters.

Comment: missing quotes after `$query11 .= " GROUP BY ZT2.Dealer` ~ should be `$query11 .= " GROUP BY ZT2.Dealer ";` and I can't help feel that the initial select query that has a nested select is missing the closing brace

Comment: Smiffy, if you dont show us the real code, you wont get a useful answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly - copy/paste error.  I checked syntax in Netbeans IDE before moving over to php.

Comment: Putting up dodgy code is not going to help anyone

Comment: @RamRaider - see edit.  This is actual syntax I am using.

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out what the final sql looks like from the code can you add what the output of `echo $query11;` shows ~ and if that query was run in your db gui does t work?

Comment: @RamRaider - editing post to add SQL Now.  If I run the SQL Statement in SSMS it runs succesfully and outputs my desired result.

Comment: Are the function `setquery11` and `loadObjectList` of your own making? I can see no way, with the standard loop you have, that the results should differ so wildly. Is it possible that one of those functions is somehow discombobulating the data / recordset??

Answer (score 0):

$db->loadObjectList() is the Joomla function that will return a list of rows.
If you want just one row you should use $db->loadObject() instead